inline function is slower
HiALL
I am using MDK arm compiler (No optimization) on stm32f030 chip.
I noticed that function declared with  __forceinline takes
more time to execute that without that. I checked that with oscilloscope.
That is very strange. I have simplified my example to the minimum and here is the
code:
static  void __forceinline inline_dbg()
{
    //cs down
    GPIOA->BRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;  
    while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}
    //cs up 
    GPIOA->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;
}

If i remove __forceinline the function executes faster.
I have checked disassembly and i found that in __forceinline function
there are two NOP's before
while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}.

In function without inline there is only one NOP.
What the hell is going on?
Why compiler modifies the code inside the function depending whether
it is inline on not?
UPD0:
I am posting disassembly for my test case.
This is the main test case.
while(1)
{
    no_inline_dbg();
    inline_dbg();
}

Theese are test functions. One is inline other is not.
static  void no_inline_dbg()
{
    //cs down
    GPIOA->BRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;
    while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}
    //cs up
    GPIOA->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;
}

static  __forceinline void inline_dbg()
{
    //cs down
    GPIOA->BRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;  
    while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}
    //cs up 
    GPIOA->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_4;
}

Here is disassembly with my comments.
/////////////////////////////////////now it goes disassembly


0x0800CB98 F7FEF85E  BL.W     no_inline_dbg (0x0800AC58) 

-------------------THIS IS INLINE SECTION!!!!!!!
0x0800CB9C BF00      NOP
--------------cs down (chip select down)-------------      
0x0800CB9E 2010      MOVS     r0,#0x10
0x0800CBA0 2109      MOVS     r1,#0x09
0x0800CBA2 06C9      LSLS     r1,r1,#27
0x0800CBA4 6288      STR      r0,[r1,#0x28]
-----------------------------------------------
0x0800CBA6 BF00      NOP    //<---- WHY THERE IS TWO NOPS HERE???       
0x0800CBA8 BF00      NOP   
------------while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}-------------   
0x0800CBAA 4807      LDR      r0,[pc,#28]  
0x0800CBAC 6900      LDR      r0,[r0,#0x10]
0x0800CBAE 2101      MOVS     r1,#0x01
0x0800CBB0 0289      LSLS     r1,r1,#10
0x0800CBB2 4008      ANDS     r0,r0,r1
0x0800CBB4 2800      CMP      r0,#0x00
0x0800CBB6 D0F8      BEQ      0x0800CBAA
---------------cs up (chip select up)------------
0x0800CBB8 2010      MOVS     r0,#0x10
0x0800CBBA 2109      MOVS     r1,#0x09
0x0800CBBC 06C9      LSLS     r1,r1,#27
0x0800CBBE 6188      STR      r0,[r1,#0x18]
------------------------------------------------
0x0800CBC0 BF00      NOP      
0x0800CBC2 E7E9      B        0x0800CB98

------------------THIS IS NOT INLINE SECTION!!!!!!
------------cs down (chip select down)-------------
0x0800AC58 2010      MOVS     r0,#0x10
0x0800AC5A 2109      MOVS     r1,#0x09
0x0800AC5C 06C9      LSLS     r1,r1,#27
0x0800AC5E 6288      STR      r0,[r1,#0x28]
----------------------------------------
0x0800AC60 BF00      NOP     
------------while((GPIOB->IDR & GPIO_PIN_10) == 0){}-----------
0x0800AC62 4806      LDR      r0,[pc,#24]  ; @0x0800AC7C
0x0800AC64 6900      LDR      r0,[r0,#0x10]
0x0800AC66 2101      MOVS     r1,#0x01
0x0800AC68 0289      LSLS     r1,r1,#10
0x0800AC6A 4008      ANDS     r0,r0,r1
0x0800AC6C 2800      CMP      r0,#0x00
0x0800AC6E D0F8      BEQ      0x0800AC62
--------------cs up (chip select up)-------------
0x0800AC70 2010      MOVS     r0,#0x10
0x0800AC72 2109      MOVS     r1,#0x09
0x0800AC74 06C9      LSLS     r1,r1,#27
0x0800AC76 6188      STR      r0,[r1,#0x18]
----------------goes to 0x0800CB9C-----------------
0x0800AC78 4770      BX       lr 


The NOPs might be to force alignment of the loop, so that it fits in fewer cache lines.  So the number of them would vary just depending on the specific address where the loop ends up, which certainly would be affected by being inlined.

If you look at the asm output by the compiler (e.g. gcc -S) rather than the disassembly of the binary, you might find hints like .align directives.

Can you post the assembly corresponding to both versions of the code (with and without inlining)?

Re: "Why compiler modifies the code inside the function depending whether it is inline on not?"  Normally, one of the main benefits of inlining is that the called function can be optimized as if it were part of the caller, which naturally results in different code.  Now you are compiling without optimizations, but even so there could be differences, e.g different register allocation.

Note that unoptimizing compilers are stupid, and often generate code that does things like store a register to the stack and then immediately load it back.  They're designed to not care at all how the code performs, so long as it is correct.  It wouldn't be too surprising if something like inlining ended up taking code that was stupid, and replacing it with something that was more stupid.

Hi Nate, thanks for reply. I was expecting that compiler without optimization should do exactly what i wrote. But i am not a compiler specialist.  I have posted a disassembly. Although that issue is not a big problem to me i decided to figure out what is going on because i am not a compiler specialist.

Ah. So first of all, the code is actually wrong. == has higher precedence than &, and so your loop will never actually loop. You can see in the disassembly that the value loaded is discarded, the test compares 0 against 0, and the branch is never taken. So maybe fix that first, so that we're analyzing code that actually means something.

HI, Sorry for delay. I have fixed the code and posted disassembly. There is still two nop's in inline function.
